# TypeScript - JavaScript using knockout.js not working in IE8 - "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, runtime-error, typescript

I have [this code (also shown below)](http://jsfiddle.net/nickkell/JrqF7/3/) that is giving me an error in IE8 but is fine in Chrome and PhantomJS.

The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method  knockout-2.2.1.debug.js, line 2319 character 35", which is called from `currentPage(pages[pages.indexOf(current) + steps]);`

I have no clue why it's not working, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var Page = (function () {
    function Page(index, name, canNavigateToPage, navigatedToThisPage) {
        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
        this.canNavigateToPage = canNavigateToPage;
        this.navigatedToThisPage = navigatedToThisPage;
    }
    Page.prototype.navigateToPage = function () {
        if (this.canNavigateToPage()) {
            this.navigatedToThisPage(this);
        }
    };
    return Page;
})();

var AccountSearchParameters = (function () {
    function AccountSearchParameters() {
        this.reference = ko.observable();
        this.scheme = ko.observable();
        this.lastName = ko.observable();
        this.sufficientInputToSearchForAccount = ko.computed(function () {

            return this.reference() && this.scheme() && this.lastName();
        }, this);
    }
    return AccountSearchParameters;
})();

function viewModel() {
    var self = this,
        currentPage = ko.observable(),
        accountSearchParameters = new AccountSearchParameters(),
        forwardPageProgressionGuards = {
            '1': function canMoveToPage2() {
                return accountSearchParameters.sufficientInputToSearchForAccount();
            },
                '2': function canMoveToPage3() {
                return true;
            },
                '3': function canMoveToPage4() {
                return true;
            }
        },
        canMoveToNextPage = function (currentlyOnPage) {
            function disallowPageMovementNotExplicitlyDefined() {
                return false;
            }

            return (forwardPageProgressionGuards[currentlyOnPage] || disallowPageMovementNotExplicitlyDefined)();
        },
        canMoveToPreviousPage = function (currentlyOnPage) {
            return currentlyOnPage > 1;
        },
        pages = [
        new Page(1, 'Customer details', function () {
            return true;
        }, function (page) {
            currentPage(page);
        }),
        new Page(2, 'Bank details', forwardPageProgressionGuards['1'], currentPage),
        new Page(3, 'Payment details', forwardPageProgressionGuards['2'], currentPage),
        new Page(4, 'Confirmation', function () {
            return true;
        }, currentPage)],
        pageNavigator = function (canNavigate, steps) {
            current = currentPage();
            console.log(canNavigate(current.index));
            if (canNavigate(current.index)) {
                currentPage(pages[pages.indexOf(current) + steps]);
            }
        };

    currentPage(pages[0]);

    self.page = ko.computed(function () {
        return currentPage();
    });

    self.accountSearchParameters = accountSearchParameters;
    self.nextPage = function () {

        pageNavigator(canMoveToNextPage, 1);
    };
    self.previousPage = function () {
        pageNavigator(canMoveToPreviousPage, -1);
    };

    self.canMoveToNext = ko.computed(function () {
        return canMoveToNextPage(currentPage().index);
    });

    return self;
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexOf in IE8 does not supported, use $.inArray

Comment: That was duuuuummmmmmmb! I was using TypeScript assuming that all of their (Microsoft's) operations would be supported by their own crappy browser. Thanks you, and thank god for unit tests.

Comment: NickL: I think even Microsoft recognizes that IE8 is crappy. They are focused on current browser support only, so that isn't surprising. That being said, you used indexOf which is JavaScript: TypeScript won't cause or fix issues like this.

Comment: No, it doesn't cause it, but it does present it on the interface, which makes it look like it's available regardless of browser. I don't know if it's possible to choose the default TypeScript definition file based on the minimum browser you're supporting.